# Flutter iOs setup

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter

I'm having trouble trying to setup Flutter on a Mac (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos);

Flutter doctor tells me:

> Xcode requires additional components to be installed in order to run. Launch Xcode and install additional required components when prompted.

and

> CocoaPods installed but not initialized. To initialize CocoaPods, run:
>   pod setup

But Xcode doesn't prompt for any install, and after run `pod setup` it is still complaining.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same steps and then I added the following command:

```
pod install
```

then `flutter clean`, and works.

Comment: Thanks, but I got the same result after the "flutter clean" command.

Comment: try run 'pod install' in the folder '/ios' from flutter project.

Answer (score 0):

Installing CoacoaPods 1.7.5:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.7.5
pod setup
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Xcode requires additional components to be installed in order to run. Launch Xcode and install additional required components when prompted.`

This is the message you typically get when you haven't installed Xcode's command line tools. Just open a terminal window and run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

and follow the prompts.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this steps for Xcode components:**

Step 1: Open System Preferences > Software update > upgrade macOS to latest os.

Step 2: Open Xcode and install additional components.

Step 3: Open Xcode and tap on Xcode menu > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools > select latest Xcode version.

**CocoaPods:**

Step 4: Open terminal > Execute the following command to get the latest stable version:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Step 5: `Flutter doctor`